# Accessing IBOutlet from subclass, outlets cannot be connected to repeating content subclass

Tags: ios, swift, button, viewcontroller, collectionview

I embedded a button in a collectionviewcell and researched on why "outlets cannot be connected to repeating content subclass". I went on and created a subclass that has the superclass of UICollectionViewCell. However, I want to set the property of my button through my viewcontroller's viewdidload. How should I do that? Here are my codes:

```swift
import UIKit

class Classic: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad()
         {
             
        
         }
         
}
class Subclass: UICollectionViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonOne: UIButton!
   
}
```

in my image, the button in the lower-left "collectionviewcell" is the button I want to manipulate
[image]

Comment: you can use closures or delegates

Comment: @jawadAli where should I declare that?? can you give me an example? thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the button properties (such as Title) in `cellForItemAt`.

Side note: using `Subclass` as the name of your class will be very confusing.

Here's a quick example:

```
class MyButtonCell: UICollectionViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonOne: UIButton!
    
    var callback: (() -> ())?
    
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        callback?()
    }
}

class TestCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    let buttonTitles: [String] = [
        "First", "Second", "Third", "etc..."
    ]

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return buttonTitles.count
    }
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCellID", for: indexPath) as! MyButtonCell
        cell.buttonOne.setTitle(buttonTitles[indexPath.item], for: [])
        cell.callback = {
            print("Button was tapped at \(indexPath)")
            // do what you want when the button is tapped
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Notice that I also added an `@IBAction` for the button *inside* the cell subclass. I also added this var / property:

```
var callback: (() -> ())?
```

That makes it easy to set up a `closure` in your controller code - again, in `cellForItemAt` - allowing your controller to handle and act when the button in a cell is tapped.

---

**Edit**

Here is a complete implementation:

```
class MyButtonCell: UICollectionViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonOne: UIButton!
    
    var callback: ((UICollectionViewCell) -> ())?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        callback?(self)
    }
}

class StevenViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    let buttonTitles: [String] = [
        "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"
    ]
    
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return buttonTitles.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCellID", for: indexPath) as! MyButtonCell

        // set the button title (and any other properties)
        cell.buttonOne.setTitle(buttonTitles[indexPath.item], for: [])

        // set the cell's callback closure
        cell.callback = { [weak self] theCell in
            guard let self = self,
                  let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: theCell)
            else { return }
            print("Button was tapped at \(indexPath)")
            // do what you want when the button is tapped
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

And here's the Storyboard source - if you haven't done this before, create a new Storyboard, select `Open As -> Source Code`, delete what's there, copy and paste the following... then you can select `Open As -> Interface Builder -Storyboard`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="16096" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="81J-PL-nYH">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="16087"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="collection view cell content view" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Steven View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="UOc-kB-D4u">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="81J-PL-nYH" customClass="StevenViewController" customModule="FirstNewMini" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="5pE-V8-AOY">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <collectionView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" dataMode="prototypes" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="eKk-rE-Fyn">
                                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="567" width="335" height="60"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99942404029999998" green="0.98555368190000003" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="60" id="t8R-1V-ELi"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <collectionViewFlowLayout key="collectionViewLayout" scrollDirection="horizontal" automaticEstimatedItemSize="YES" minimumLineSpacing="10" minimumInteritemSpacing="10" id="34u-td-lg8">
                                    <size key="itemSize" width="60" height="60"/>
                                    <size key="headerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
                                    <size key="footerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
                                    <inset key="sectionInset" minX="0.0" minY="0.0" maxX="0.0" maxY="0.0"/>
                                </collectionViewFlowLayout>
                                <cells>
                                    <collectionViewCell opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" reuseIdentifier="myCellID" id="slK-WV-d6z" customClass="MyButtonCell" customModule="FirstNewMini" customModuleProvider="target">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="60" height="60"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                        <collectionViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" id="inr-uV-Mkf">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="60" height="60"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <subviews>
                                                <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="jO2-43-Y97">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="7" y="15" width="46" height="30"/>
                                                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.92143100499999997" green="0.92145264149999995" blue="0.92144101860000005" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                    <state key="normal" title="Button"/>
                                                    <connections>
                                                        <action selector="buttonTapped:" destination="slK-WV-d6z" eventType="touchUpInside" id="ILI-g9-h3v"/>
                                                    </connections>
                                                </button>
                                            </subviews>
                                            <constraints>
                                                <constraint firstItem="jO2-43-Y97" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="inr-uV-Mkf" secondAttribute="centerY" id="K8s-Jl-sfY"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="jO2-43-Y97" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="inr-uV-Mkf" secondAttribute="centerX" id="kF4-R0-H31"/>
                                            </constraints>
                                        </collectionViewCellContentView>
                                        <connections>
                                            <outlet property="buttonOne" destination="jO2-43-Y97" id="EkG-Dz-2DC"/>
                                        </connections>
                                    </collectionViewCell>
                                </cells>
                            </collectionView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="OxZ-Gp-ekf" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="eKk-rE-Fyn" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="Gua-Zi-IFQ"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="OxZ-Gp-ekf" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="eKk-rE-Fyn" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="40" id="I6q-K5-nN3"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="eKk-rE-Fyn" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="OxZ-Gp-ekf" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="sCP-Nn-RqH"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="OxZ-Gp-ekf"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="collectionView" destination="eKk-rE-Fyn" id="rxw-DZ-Kpi"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="Ap0-Qs-M9q" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="199.19999999999999" y="155.17241379310346"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

The result when you run it should look like this (I gave the collection view a yellow background to make it easy to see the frame):

[image]

Comment: Hey I tried to implement this but can you explain more on how I can use the functions you wrote? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting button access in viewDidLoad(), this is what you can do. Create an @IBOutlet of collectionView into your view controller class.

After that register your custom subclass of UICollectionViewCell, in your case its "Subclass"

After that use dataSource method of collectionView to load the cell and get access to the button.

```
class Classic: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

   @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
   override func viewDidLoad()
     {
        // Register your cell
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "Subclass", bundle: nil)
        collectionView?.registerNib(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
     }     
    
    // Collection view data source method 
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     
    // get your cell 
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Subclass

      // here you will have access to your button
      cell.buttonOne.setTitle("Button Title", for: .normal)
       
     // To handle tap on button
     cell.buttonOne.tag = indexPath.row 
     cell.buttonOne.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)   

    return cell
}

    @objc func didTapButton(sender: UIButton) {
        print("button tapped at index:-", sender.tag)
    }
     
}
```

Use other data source and delegates of collection view as per your need. Hope this solution works for you.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the reply!! However, when I tried this code, it asked me "Type 'Classic' does not conform to protocol 'UICollectionViewDataSource' Do you want to add protocol stubs?", should I add this protocol stub?

Comment: @StevenOh yes please add the protocol stubs, they are required methods of UICollectionViewDataSource.

Answer (score 1):

- Add CollectionView outlet from storyboard
- Add Button Tapped block in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
import UIKit

class Classic: UIViewController {

    @IBoutlet weak var collectionView : UICollectionView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
             
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(SubClass.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
         
}

extension Classic : UICollectionViewDelegate {

}

extension Classic : UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.buttonTapped = {
            print("Button Tapped")
        }

        return cell
    }
}

class Subclass: UICollectionViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonOne: UIButton!

    var buttonTapped : () -> () = { }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.buttonTapped()
     }
   
}
```